# watching on the select item in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive

I am having a div which contains a set of dropdown to select a criteria. We can add or delete criteria using the plus and minus buttons. The values to fill in the dropdown is fetched from an API.

The code for the UI is below:

```
<form novalidate="" role="form" name="filterForm" class="form-inline">
  <div ng-repeat="criteria in criterias">
    <div class="m-b">
      <div class="form-group s-b" style="width: 150px;">
        <span>Country</span>
        <select class="form-control" ng-options="item for item in country" name="account" ng-model="criteria.country" style="max-width:100%"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group s-b" style="width: 150px;">
        <span>State</span>
        <select ng-options="item for item in state" class="form-control" name="account" ng-model="criteria.state" style="max-width:100%"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group s-b" style="width: 150px;">
        <span>City</span>
        <select class="form-control" ng-options="item for item in city" name="account" ng-model="criteria.city" style="max-width:100%;"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group s-b" style="width: 150px;">
        <span>Predicate</span>
        <select class="form-control" name="account" ng-model="criteria.predicate" style="max-width:100%">
          <option value="matches">Matches</option>
          <option value="not-matches">Not Matches</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group s-b" style="width: 100px;">
        <span>Value</span>
        <select class="form-control" ng-options="item for item in value" name="account" ng-model="criteria.value" style="max-width:100%;"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group s-b" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <span>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pad-btn" type="submit" ng-click="addCriteria()">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pad-btn" type="submit" ng-click="deleteCriteria(criteria)">
            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pad-btn align-center" type="submit" ng-click="searchParams(filterForm)">Submit
                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning pad-btn align-center" type="submit" ng-click="resetFilter()">Reset
                        <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
  </button>
</form>
```

I need to watch for the dropdown and handle the event for the corresponding criteria and update the other corresponding dropdown elements for that criteria. Please let me know how to handle the $watch element when there are many criterias when user has added using the plus button as I am not advanced programmer on AngularJs.

**Updated Question**

Based on the suggestion I have used the `ng-change` instead of `$watch` and I am now able to handle the event and also get the reference to the `criteria` object. After handling the event, I need to update the `state` value for the selected `country`. I have updated the Plnkr link with the code below but the `state` drop down is not getting updated even after updated the scope using `$scope.criterias[index] = user;`. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Updated code to handle the change event:

```
$scope.handleClassification = function(index){
        var user = $scope.criterias[index];
        user.config=["California"];
        $scope.criterias[index] = user;
        console.log(user);

    }
```

I am providing the updated plnkr link for more details - [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7BAL8jb44MrspmFTP6WF?p=preview)

Comment: what is your criteria?

Comment: I would use ng-change directive instead of watching Checkout link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Comment: @Poyraz criteria is a object which contains country, state, city, predicate and value. This is one criteria. User can create multiple criteria.

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/annavester/Zd6uX/ out...

Comment: I have updated the question. Now I am using the `ng-change` instead of `$watch` but unable to updated the remaining drop down values for the selected criteria.

Comment: Thanks @Moid Mohd. In the static example, if I select a country, then city and finally the suburb and then I change the country, the suburb does not change. How to get this fixed. I am having the similar requirement in one of the project.

Comment: @Pradeep I don't get why you are only sending index and your mistake was setting config value to an array change it to string and it will work... Please explain what is your point more clearly...

Comment: @Poyraz Yilmaz When I select a country, I need to update the states for that country. Now there can be many countries since the user can add multiple criteria using the plus symbol. All criteria are stored inside an array. To know which criteria to be updated we need to pass the index. I get the index, fetch the corresponding array of cities and update to the corresponding country. Please click on the Plunkr to get a feel of what I am working on.

Comment: @Moid Mohd I am not able to select the country from the drop down in the fiddle.

Comment: Sorry bowser got closed before saving...See this.. https://jsfiddle.net/moidmw/t5qkL174/5/

Comment: @MoidMohd Still not working. select a country, then state and then city. Now change the country. The city is still pointing to the selected one.

Comment: Oh sorry...I didnt saw the city...wait.. I'll check and update the answer

Comment: @PoyrazYilmaz Even if I change the value of the config from array to string, the UI is not updated with the value. It still behaves like a dropdown with default values. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way..I guess you want to update `select` in a cascade way...

Your HTML file:

```
  <div ng-controller="StaticCtrl">
      <h1>Static - Oriented</h1>
      <p>This approach may be better when you have the entire dataset</p>
    <div>
        Country: 
        <select id="country" ng-model="cities" ng-options="country for (country, cities) in countries" ng-change="onChange()">
          <option value=''>Select</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        State: <select id="city" ng-disabled="!cities" ng-model="suburbs" ng-options="city for (city, suburbs) in cities"><option value=''>Select</option></select>
    </div>
    <div>
        City: <select id="suburb" ng-disabled="!suburbs" ng-model="suburb" ng-options="suburb for suburb in suburbs"><option value=''>Select</option></select>        
    </div>
  </div>
```

and your JS:

```
    function StaticCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.countries = {
    'India': {
      'UP': ['Noida', 'Lucknow', 'Agra'],
      'Maharashtra': ['Mumbai']
    },
    'USA': {
      'San Francisco': ['SOMA', 'Richmond', 'Sunset'],
      'Los Angeles': ['Burbank', 'Hollywood']
    },
    'canada': {
      'People dont live here': ['igloo', 'cave']
    }
  };
  $scope.onChange = function() {
  console.log("Asdasd");
    $scope.suburb = '';
  }
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/moidmw/t5qkL174/8/) is the fiddle..

Comment: What if there are multiple sets of such values. like 

1. country (dropdown)  state (dropdown)   city (dropdown)     +  -
2. country (dropdown)  state (dropdown)   city (dropdown)     +  -
3. country (dropdown)  state (dropdown)   city (dropdown)     +  -

I need to update the state for the second item.

Comment: Could you please let me know once you have updated the code to handle the issue on city. I finally got the solution to the problem. Thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/moidmw/t5qkL174/8/ ...here is the updated fiddle.. Just reset the `ng-modal` value `suburb` on change.. I have updated the answer too..

Comment: What if I just want to update the states on selecting the country butt cities should be by default load all the cities from a scope attribute. Only when we select the state all the cities specific to the state should get populated. Please let me know.

Comment: What if I want to get the selected country and selected city in my controller? How do I get the selected values from the dropdown?

Comment: Use the `ng-modal` variable to get those selected value from the dropdown to your controller.  And for creating an independent cities dropdown remove `ng-disabled` from cities dropdown and also `ng-change` from country. I guess that should do.